# Why is parameter for onChange(of:perform:) captured?

Tags: swift, swiftui, automatic-ref-counting

I was using the [`onChange(of:perform:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/onchange(of:perform:)) SwiftUI modifier. I then wanted to get the old value, to compare it with the new value. I read the documentation, which says:

> The previous value may be captured by the closure to compare it to the new value.

With an example:

```
.onChange(of: playState) { [playState] newState in
    model.playStateDidChange(from: playState, to: newState)
}
```

My question is why in the example is `playState` captured in the `[ ]`? The `playState` value could easily be accessed without passing it in. In addition, this isn't part of a class, so I assume there is no way to create a strong reference by capturing `self` of some sort.

Why is the example written like this?

Comment: If you don't do that, `playState` will have changed by the time this closure executes, and will be the same as `newState`

Comment: @NewDev So does this mean that `onChange` gets called _before_ the value of `playState` has changed (like a `willSet`)? For me they are both the same value, as described in an issue [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/650923).

Comment: My understanding is that it's called after, so it requires to capture the value by the closure. The capture happens when the closure is defined, which is when the "old" value is still the "current", so you capture the current (soon-to-be old) state into a local state captured by the closure.

Comment: @NewDev Ok that makes more sense. The bug of them being the same is probably what has confused me most about it. Am I correct in thinking that, just before the closure of `onChange` is called, the captured variable is then set its value? Then the real value of `playState` would be set _in between_ setting the captured value and calling the closure? Still a bit confusing to me, seems more advanced than I originally thought! 

Comment: @NewDev And how does Swift handle the difference between just accessing `playState` compared to capturing with `[playState]`? Not even the Swift docs has this (at least from what I can find), and I think answering this would answer my entire question.

Comment: If it helps anybody who comes across this post in the future, learning about capture lists helps understand what is happening with this syntax: https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/swifts-closure-capturing-mechanics/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Under "normal" circumstances, a closure defined inside an immutable value-type (e.g. a `struct`) captures its value, which doesn't change, so all is good.

```
struct Foo {
  var a = "original"
  
  func makeFn() -> () -> Void {
     return { print(a) }
  }
}

var foo = Foo()
let fn = foo.makeFn()
foo.a = "changed"

fn() // "original"
```

But with `@State`, the actual value is stored in some global storage that SwiftUI maintains, so it basically behaves as if it's having reference semantics.

When the closure is called, the state value has already changed, so doing `print(a)` as above accesses a value through the `@State` property wrapper, which retrieves the then-updated value.

To counter that, you can capture the property into the closure's local variable with a capture list:

```
return { [a] in print(a) }
```

This is of course a simplified example, and SwiftUI might be doing other things behind the scenes, but I think it conveys the point.

---

To see the difference in SwiftUI, try the following:

```
.onChange(of: playState) { [playState] newState in
    print(playState, self.playState, newState)
}
```

The output would be something like this:

```
original new new
```

`playState` is the captured local variable at the time the closure was defined (i.e. when `body` was computed), `self.playState` accesses the value via `@State`, which has changed, and `newState` is obviously the passed-in parameter with the new value.