# Working with multiple onReceive with @EnvironmentObject in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I came across one problem while working with the @EnvironmentObject in SwiftUI. I have created an ObservableObject **update** in a separate file. Now, I am referring this as a @EnvironmentObject from 2 different View(View 1 and View 2). I have to do certain tasks in View1 and View2 when **update** value changes. So I am using .onReceive() in both View1 and View2.
Now, I want that the .onReceive function in View1 should be called before the .onReceive function in View2 when the **update** value changes. So can someone please suggest how can I do this?

Comment: hard to tell what you are doing without any code or understanding of your app,
but the `onReceive` will be done mostly at the same time, as far as I know. If `onReceive` is really appropriate 
for your app, then you could try delaying the things you do in your second `onReceive`, by wrapping the content in a
`DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {...}` for example.

Comment: @workingdog Simply adding DispatchQueue.main.async worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We don't use `onReceive` with `ObservableObject`. We either init the object inside the `@StateObject` property wrapper or `@ObservedObject` if it was init somewhere else. These property wrappers mean the View's body will automatically be called whenever any of the `@Published` vars change, which calls `objectWillChange.send()` which you can also do manually. If you want to cause a side effect by a var of the object changing you can use [`onChange(of:perform:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/onchange(of:perform:)) on a View inside `body`. Since the body is called every time the object changes, `onChange` will also be called and if the value passed in is different from the previous time then the block runs.

E.g.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var progress = UserProgress()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Your score is \(progress.score)")
            ...
        }
        .onChange(of: player.score) { [oldScore = player.score] newScore in
            print("changed from \(oldScore) to \(newScore)")
        }
    }
}
```

Learn about the use of a capture list for oldScore/newScore [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64189094/why-is-parameter-for-onchangeofperform-captured).