# SwiftUI onChange capture

Tags: swiftui

In many tutorials, it is recommended to put [t] in the `.onChange` closure. For example

```swift
.onChange(of: t) { [t] newValue in
            let oldValue = t
            if newValue % oldValue == 2 {
                print("2")
            } else {
                print("not 2")
            }
        }
```

What's the reason for that? It looks no difference if i remove it.

Comment: If you don't need old value then it is not needed

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is parameter for onChange(of:perform:) captured?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64189094/why-is-parameter-for-onchangeofperform-captured)

Answer (score 0):

`[t]` is the equivalent of `oldValue`, if you don't need the oldValue you don't have to add it. Your code is the same as:

```
.onChange(of: t) { [t] newValue in
            if newValue % t == 2 {
                print("2")
            } else {
                print("not 2")
            }
        }
```

Comment: Even if I remove `[t]`, I still can get the old value of `t`. For example, this kind of code still works:  .onChange(of: t) { newValue in
            if newValue % t == 2 {
                print("2")
            } else {
                print("not 2")
            }
        }

Comment: yes, because you have the t in the .onChange(of: t), that is where it takes it from, that [t] seems to be kind of optional in this context, and it is at your latitude to add it or not, you could add it to have a cleaner approach